# Match shape colour to cell color - vba

Tags: vba, excel, colors, shapes

I am looking to set up a basic loop to set the color of each shape in the worksheet to match a corresponding cell in a table (conditional formatted).

I have the following

```
dim countryShape as shape

For Each countryShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes

countryShape.Range.Interior.Color = Application.VLookup(countryShape.Name, ActiveSheet.Range("D3:H19"), 2, 0).Interior.Color

Next countryShape
```

However, I get a

> run time error 424, 'Object required'

I am guessing it is to do with the format of color application (i.e .interior.color for cells and .fill.forecolor for shape) however any combination I have tried so far is yet to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the color of a shape, you need to change the Fill.ForeColor property. Also you  cannot use Vlookup as it will return you the cell value not the cell color.

Please try it like this...

```
Dim countryShape As Shape
Dim ColorCell As Range
For Each countryShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Set ColorCell = Range("D3:D19").Find(what:=countryShape.Name, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not ColorCell Is Nothing Then
        'get the shape color from corresponding cell in column E
        countryShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ColorCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color 
    End If
Next countryShape
```

Comment: ah, this works perfectly except for something that I failed to mention. the cells in the table are colored according to conditional formatting. Is there any way to transfer the formatting color (given that it doesn't technically count as a cell color?)  (upvoted for the massive help ty)

Comment: ah i found the solution . to use colorcell.DISPLAYFORMAT.interior.color.

Thank you so much for your help sir!

Comment: @IIJHFII You're welcome! Glad you tweaked it correctly.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you both .

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim shp         As Shape
    Dim fancyCell   As Range

    Dim colorR      As Long
    Dim colorG      As Long
    Dim colorB      As Long
    Dim colorFancy  As Long

    Set fancyCell = Range("A1")
    colorFancy = fancyCell.Interior.Color

    colorR = colorFancy And 255
    colorG = colorFancy \ 256 And 255
    colorB = colorFancy \ 256 ^ 2 And 255

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(colorR, colorG, colorB)
    Next shp

End Sub
```

The shape expects RGB color, thus you may give it, taking the color from the cell. The `RGB()` returns the same `Long`, which is used in the `Range.Interior.Color`, thus you may also simply use:
      `shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = colorFancy.Interior.Color`

As proposed by the answer from @sktneer.